# How to get latlng on moving marker on leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I want to get latlng on drage the marker. I tried this code, but it return underfined.

````
var marker = L.marker([51.502652, -0.091667], {draggable: true}).addTo(mymap);

marker.on("dragend", function(e){
  var newCoords = e.latlng.toString();
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var marker = L.marker([{{ $lat }}, {{ $lng }}], {draggable: true}).addTo(map);

marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
    var lat = marker.getLatLng().lat; 
    var lng = marker.getLatLng().lng);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The event isn't the marker - you need the object that's the target of the event. So.....

```
marker.on("dragend", function(e){
  var newCoords = e.target.getLatLng().toString();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `)` after `.lng` at the end of line 5:

```
var lng = marker.getLatLng().lng);
```